# Auth0 does not return user information immediately after creation

Tags: auth0

Auth0:

1. Sign up your user
2. Grep userId from response (I used *jq*)
3. Get user information by id immediately >> **Returns nothing!**
4. Repeat step 3 in 1 second >> **OK**

Check out this script

```
user=$(curl -s -X POST -d 'email=test1@mail.com&password=test1Pass&connection=Username-Password-Authentication' 'https://your-acc.auth0.com/dbconnections/signup')
userId=$(echo $user | jq -r '._id')

curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer insert-token' "https://your-acc.auth0.com/api/v2/users?q=user_id:\""$userId"\""
sleep 1
curl -X GET -H 'Authorization: Bearer insert-token' "https://your-acc.auth0.com/api/v2/users?q=user_id:\""$userId"\""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix it by calling

```
/api/v2/users/{userId}
```

which returns single user. Surprisingly it works just fine.

Anyway, it does not solve my problem if I want to request multiple users at a time.

Did not get any response at auth0 forum.